# Run all tests in namespace using Nunit3-console.exe

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0

After pouring over the NUnit 3 documentation on [Test Selection Language](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Test-Selection-Language) and trying a few combinations, I still cannot figure out how to run all the tests within a specific namespace.

The most obvious attempt being:

```
nunit3-console.exe --where "test == 'MyNamespace.Subnamespace'" Tests.dll
```

Unfortunately, this reports zero matching tests, although using the `--explore` options I can see many tests within that namespace.

Do I need to use regular expression/wildcards to accomplish this? The NUnit docs hint otherwise, but given this doesn't work maybe I do.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the following works:

```
nunit3-console.exe --where "test =~ 'MyNamespace.Subnamespace'" Tests.dll
```

Note the squiggle `=~` is a regex operator.

This is a bit of a surprise because the only example mentioning namespaces in the documentation uses the `==` syntax which, given my original experimentation, would not have any effect.

Comment: The original works (for me) as well. You haven't indicated what version of the nunit3-console runner you are using. Perhaps you have an older one?

Comment: Regarding the docs... they mention that you can give the name of any test. I suppose it may not be clear to all readers that a namespace containing tests __is__ a test, just the same as a class containing tests. That's a general feature of most testing frameworks implemented using the Composite pattern.